# Подготовленный запрос sqlite3 не выполняется

Tags: sqlite3, php

Есть функция сортирующая контент. На вход посылаем поле, по которому будет сортироваться контент, и мод(ASC и DESC). Не используя stmt, выборка проходила на ура. Но решил ввести защиту от инъекций и не сортирует.

```
//Сортировка
function sortCourse($value,$mod){
    if($mod=='up')
        $sql='SELECT id,name_course,author,category,year,status,mark FROM courses ORDER BY :value ASC';
    elseif($mod=='down')
        $sql='SELECT id,name_course,author,category,year,status,mark FROM courses ORDER BY :value DESC';
    else
        $sql='SELECT id,name_course,author,category,year,status,mark FROM courses ORDER BY :value ASC';       
    $stmt=$this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value',$value);
    $res=$stmt->execute();
return $this->sqltoArray($res);
}
//Перевод из sql в массив
function sqltoArray($result){
    $arr=Array();
    while($row=$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    $arr[]=$row;
    };
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подумайте что будет с текстом запроса когда драйвер подставит туда значение :value. Правильно будет просто строка. Т.е. `order by 'ляляля'` или число `order by 1`... Поставить имя поля вам туда не удастся, параметры так не работают. Чтоб избавиться от инъекции надо просто добавить проверку и сформировать запрос самостоятельно, без параметра. Как-то так:

```
if ($value==1) $sortcolumn = 'field1';
if ($mod=='up') {
  $direction = 'ASC';
} else {
  $direction = 'DESC';
}
$sql = '... order by '.$sortcolumn.' '.$direction;
```